# Best way to store unchangable information

Tags: android

I'm developing an android game, and on each level, i have the level information written on the code, like these example.

```
LevelOneballsNumber = 5;
LevelTwoballsNumber = 7;
Level one = new Level(1, LevelOneballsNumber , #FF462F);
Level two = new Level(2, LevelTwoBallsNumber, #FFFFFF);
```

This approach seems very hardcoding to me. There's some way to store this kind of information (information that never changed), and get them during the game?

Comment: @FrankN.Stein i've around 20 levels, and each level needs around 10 different variables, as i said, this is just an example.

Answer (score 3):

you can save the information on file , and get it from there . 
or to make a "manager class" or some static class that will contain all the information of all the levels .

Answer (score 3):

So based on the information that you have provided, personally I see two approaches.

**Approach 1:**

One of things which you could do, is use the sql lite database if you are really concerned about keeping them as unchangable and it will persist and you can read out of there.

**Approach 2:**

The Other way is to make it a static class and then have reference of it for each user, but I am guessing you would have to implement a multiton design pattern to be able to effectively do it, you could do this but would involve a little more complexity than using the database directly.

I am sure there are more ways to do this, at the end of the day your call, but personally I would go the Database way.

DBs FTW!

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to store the information in an xml (or json, etc) file as your asset, and then parse it in runtime with your favorite xml / json parser.  This allows a more flexibility in the schema than storing it in a relational database, and can be easily edited independent of the code.